# Calling Javascript Function from Hyperlink

Tags: javascript, function, hyperlink

I am working on a page that contains a digital phone directory.  The names and numbers are listed, but I would like for more details about the entry to display in a popup when the name is clicked.  Unfortunately, I am having a problem with the Javascript.  I am very new to this language, but I think that either the code within the function I declared is wrong, the syntax of the argument I am passing is incorrect, or I omitted an essential part of the code.  Any assistance you can provide on this issue would be greatly appreciated.

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<script>
Function DisplayContactDetail(contact, windowname) {
    window.open(contact, windowname);
}
</script>
<title>Cigna Security & Reception Phone Directory</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="centerelement">
        <div id="indexpageheader">
            CIGNA SECURITY & RECEPTION DIGITAL PHONE DIRECTORY
        </div>
    </div>
    <table>
        <th colspan=2 width="auto">
            ALLIEDBARTON
        </th>
        <tr>
            <td width="50%">
                <a href="" onclick="DisplayContactDetail('cigna.com','ContactDetail')">
                    NEPA District Office
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>(610) 954-8590</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="50%">Post Watch</td>
            <td>(800) 643-8714</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So, what's the problem? Nothing happens? Getting unexpected results? An error occurs?

Comment: Nothing happens when I click on hyperlink.

Comment: <html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

<script>
Function DisplayContactDetail (contact,windowname)
{

window.open (contact,windowname);

}

</script>

<title>Cigna Security & Reception Phone Directory</title>
</head>

<body>

<div class="centerelement"><div id="indexpageheader">CIGNA SECURITY & RECEPTION DIGITAL PHONE DIRECTORY</div></div>

Comment: <table>
            <th colspan=2 width="auto">ALLIEDBARTON</th>
            <tr>
                        <td width="50%"><a href="" onclick="DisplayContactDetail('http://www.cigna.com','ContactDetail')">NEPA District Office</a></td><td>(610) 954-8590</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>

                        <td width="50%">Post Watch</td><td>(800) 643-8714</td>
            </tr>
</table>

Comment: It still does not do anything when I click on the link.  I have included the complete code from the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've a quoting error in the value of the `onclick` attribute:

```
<a href="" onclick="DisplayContactDetail("http://www.cigna.com")">
```

Should be for example:

```
<a href="" onclick="DisplayContactDetail('http://www.cigna.com')">
```

Also `Function` should be `function`, JS is case-sensitive.